# Tango with Django - issue with running the populate_rango.py script

Tags: python, django

I forked the official tango_with_django repo on github (https://github.com/leifos/tango_with_django), and I'm trying to populate the site with the data from populate_rango.py. However, when I ran it, I got this error:

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column name is not unique

Anyone know where I should begin to start debugging? In case it's relevant, I also pip installed South, but when I ran

```
python manage.py schemamigration rango --initial
```

I got:

```
Unknown command: 'schemamigration'
```

Anyone have any ideas about what to do on these two issues?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319477/tango-with-django-issue-with-running-the-populate-rango-py-script Check this out