# Error running Django Populate Script - Tango with Django

Tags: python, django

Am deploying the online tutorial (Tango with Django) app on python anywhere but am having problems with the populate_rango script. I keep getting the column name is not unique error with a long traceback. 
Anybody know what the problem is. Help needed.Should be a quick fix. 
I noticed somebody else had the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319477/tango-with-django-issue-with-running-the-populate-rango-py-script) but it was unanswered.

populate_rango.py

```
import os 

def populate():
    python_cat = add_cat(name='Python', views=128, likes=64)

    add_page(cat=python_cat, 
    title="Official Python Tutorial",
    views=25,
    url="http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/")

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
    title="How to Think like a Computer Scientist",
    views=20,
    url="http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/")

    add_page(cat=python_cat,
    title="Learn Python in 10 minutes",
    views=12,
    url="http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python/")

    django_cat = add_cat(name="Django", views=32, likes=16)

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
    title="Official Django Tutorial",
    views=55,
    url="http://djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
    title="Django Rocks",
    views=34,
    url="http://www.djangorocks.com/")

    add_page(cat=django_cat,
    title="How to Tango with Django",
    views=49,
    url="htttp://www.tangowithdjango.com/")

    frame_cat = add_cat(name="Other Frameworks", views=32, likes=16)

    add_page(cat=frame_cat, 
    title="Bottle",
    views=78,
    url="http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/")

    add_page(cat=frame_cat, 
    title="Flask",
    views=29,
    url="http://flask.pocoo.org")

    # Print out what we have added to the user. 
    for c in Category.objects.all():
        for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
            print "- {0} - {1}".format(str(c), str(p))

def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0):
    p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title, url=url, views=views)[0]
    return p

def add_cat(name, views, likes):
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name, views=views, likes=likes)[0]
    return c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Staring Rango population script..."
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tango_with_django.settings')
    from rango.models import Category, Page
    populate()



Staring Rango population script...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "populate_rango.py", line 67, in <module>
    populate()
  File "populate_rango.py", line 4, in populate
    python_cat = add_cat(name='Python', views=128, likes=64)
  File "populate_rango.py", line 60, in add_cat
    c = Category.objects.get_or_create(name=name, views=views, likes=likes)[0]
  File "/home/timkaboya/.virtualenvs/rango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 154, in get_or_create
    return self.get_queryset().get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/home/timkaboya/.virtualenvs/rango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 391, in get_or_create
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/timkaboya/.virtualenvs/rango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 383, in get_or_create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/home/timkaboya/.virtualenvs/rango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 545, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/home/timkaboya/.virtualenvs/rango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 573, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
  File "/home/timkaboya/.virtualenvs/rango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 654, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "/home/timkaboya/.virtualenvs/rango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 687, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/home/timkaboya/.virtualenvs/rango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 232, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/home/timkaboya/.virtualenvs/rango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1514, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/home/timkaboya/.virtualenvs/rango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 903, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/timkaboya/.virtualenvs/rango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 69, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/timkaboya/.virtualenvs/rango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/timkaboya/.virtualenvs/rango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 99, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/home/timkaboya/.virtualenvs/rango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 53, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/timkaboya/.virtualenvs/rango/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 451, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: column name is not unique
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to simulate the problem through the interactive console (python manage.py shell):

```
>>> from rango.models import Category
>>> print Category.objects.all()
[]
>>> c = Category(name="Test") # Add new category named Test
>>> c.save()
>>> print Category.objects.all()
[<Category: Test>]
>>> c = Category(name="Test", view="1", like="1") # Try adding another record named Test with view and like values
>>> c.save()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 546, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 650, in save_base
    result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 215, in _insert
    return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1675, in insert_query
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 937, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.py", line 41, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 364, in execute
    six.reraise(utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 362, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
IntegrityError: column name is not unique
>>> c = Category(name="Test2", view="1", like="1") # --- This one worked because I'm adding a unique name ---
>>> c.save()
>>> print Category.objects.all()
[<Category: Test>, <Category: Test2>]
```

Since the **name** attribute in the **Category** model is unique:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
```

... in short, I was trying to add "Test" in the **name** column but that value already exists.

UPDATE:

Confirming the solution:

1. Delete the rango.db database
2. Run "python manage.py syncdb" to recreate the db
3. Run "python populate_rango.py".

So the error really is coming from duplicate name values in the database.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

From what I remember I had same problem I've found my old project please check below script:

```
import os

def populate():
python_cat = add_cat('Python')
add_page(cat=python_cat,
    title="Official Python Tutorial",
    url="http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/")

add_page(cat=python_cat,
    title="How to Think like a Computer Scientist",
    url="http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/")

add_page(cat=python_cat,
    title="Learn Python in 10 Minutes",
    url="http://www.korokithakis.net/tutorials/python/")

django_cat = add_cat("Django")

add_page(cat=django_cat,
    title="Official Django Tutorial",
    url="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/")

add_page(cat=django_cat,
    title="Django Rocks",
    url="http://www.djangorocks.com/")

add_page(cat=django_cat,
    title="How to Tango with Django",
    url="http://www.tangowithdjango.com/")

frame_cat = add_cat("Other Frameworks")

add_page(cat=frame_cat,
    title="Bottle",
    url="http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/")

add_page(cat=frame_cat,
    title="Flask",
    url="http://flask.pocoo.org")

# Print out what we have added to the user.
for c in Category.objects.all():
    for p in Page.objects.filter(category=c):
        print "- {0} - {1}".format(str(c), str(p))

def add_page(cat, title, url, views=0):
p = Page.objects.get_or_create(category=cat, title=title, url=url, views=views)[0]
return p

def add_cat(name):
c = Category.objects.create(name=name)
return c

# Start execution here!
if __name__ == '__main__':
print "Starting Rango population script..."
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tango_with_django.settings')
from rango.models import Category, Page

populate()
```

Comment: Yeah, same script. Only that mine has views and likes added under both Category and Pages. How did you solve this problem. Curious to know. This script works on my terminal but it doesn't on the PythonAnywhere console.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just had same problem and here's my solution: main problem was `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tango_with_django_project.settings')`, my project directory named as just `tango_with_django`. Don't really know if it means, but I also placed these lines right after importing `os`(don't forget to remove `os.environ.` from the bottom)

So it looks like this:

`import os`

`os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tango_with_django.settings')`

`import django`

`django.setup()`

`from rango.models import Category, Page`